# Finding embedded information with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am relatively new to web scraping and BeautifulSoup in general. So, please forgive me if this is a novice question. If there is a similar article that answers my question, please send me the link.

To make it short, I am trying to scrape the conjugation charts from a website. This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/finir.html"
page=requests.get(url) soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class":"conjugBloc"})
try: 
 for x in table: 
   print (x.find('p').text) 
except AttributeError: print("Attribute Error")
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
Présent

je finis
tu finis 
il finit 
nous finissons 
vous finissez 
ils finissent
```

However, I get instead:

```
Présent
Passé composé
Imparfait
Plus-que-parfait
Passé simple
Passé antérieur
Futur simple
Futur antérieur
Présent
Passé
Imparfait
Plus-que-parfait
Présent
Passé première forme
Passé deuxième forme
Attribute Error
```

I am getting the titles, but not the information that belongs to them. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated !

This is the source code of the website section that I am analysing. 
[image: This is the source code of the website]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
table = soup.select('div.tempsBloc[id="temps0"] ~p')
targets = str(table[0]).split('<br/>')
for target in targets:
    print(BeautifulSoup(target,'lxml').text)
```

Output:

```
je finis
tu finis
il finit
nous finissons
vous finissez
ils finissent
```